# With laravel blade input id = ex. id="group-{{$category->id}}" howto name old('xxxxx')

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

With laravel blade
if input id = ex. id="group-{{$category->id}}"

howto name old('xxxxx') ?

Comment: What's the relation between `id="group-{{$category->id}}"` and `old('xxxxx')`?

Comment: require a little more information to clear up what you are trying to achive here

Comment: Please provide more info, as much as info as possible this is `NOT GOOGLE SEARCH`

Answer (score 0):

The `old` method takes the `name` attribute and not the `id`, add the attribute name to the element and then you can set the value to `{{ old('group-'.$category->id) }}`

More here: [Old Input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#old-input)

Answer (score -1):

You can first create a variable in PHP with -

```
<?php
$temp = 'group-'.$category->id;
?>
```

then in your input field - 
you can use

```
{{Input::old($temp)}}
```